# Meaning of ものの。 in this sentence

Tags: particle-の, reading-comprehension, sentence-final-particles

> だから、一緒に行動するなら、この気まずさを少しでもほぐしておきたい。
> ここは、俺が大人になるとこだよなと思い、歩み寄ったものの。

What exactly is the use of ものの。 in this sentence? The character had a fight with his friend and because they need to work together, he says want to clear up the awkwardness.

> ここは、俺が大人になるとこだよなと思い、歩み寄ったものの。

If I got it right the first part is akin "Here I'll become an adult" like "I'll act as an adult"

> 歩み寄ったものの。

"Although I tried to compromise"?

Comment: Putting aside the question you're asking, how did you get anything about "compromise" out of 歩み寄った? That means something like "stepped up" (literally, approached by walking). Anyway, ものの can really only be もの as a nominalizer + の as a sentence-ender. I'm not sure exactly where the confusion lies?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 歩み寄る can mean "to compromise" according to multiple dictionaries I checked (and how this is derived from the literal meaning of the word seems evident). And ものの is a fixed expression, if that's not what you meant?

Comment: As for the [ものの](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE-646370) part, @Blueshell correctly interprets it as *although*.  The sentences that follow this part will tell us what happened although he tried to compromise. So I'd like to see why you're confused in more detail, too. (I think compromise is a valid translation of 歩み寄る here, unless the context clearly shows that he physically moved closer to the friend {which is possible}.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 歩み寄る according to 大辞林: 互いに譲り合って，双方の主張や条件を一致する方向に近づける。「労使が―・る」

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this ものの is "although", and you can find lots of examples [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE-monono-meaning/). However, this sentence is special in that the corresponding main clause has been intentionally left out, effectively leaving the reader dangling. So it's more like this:

> 歩み寄ったものの。
> I tried to compromise, however... <sub>(end of the sentence)</sub>

The sentence might have been a little easier to understand if there had been an ellipsis after ものの. Usually, you can expect the corresponding bad consequence is described in the next sentence.